# Export problems with civi 5.10

Tags: export, field-mapping, 5.10.x

We have two sites, both D7.66 both civi 5.10

One wants to export activity data including target contact data from an activity search

They have been using this process and mapping for several years but recent exports are pulling through activity data and no contact data

The other is exporting grant data. And the grant type field is no longer pulling through the grant type label. Instead it is displaying a 4 digit number. This does not equate to the grant type value.

I know this should be two separate questions and maybe soon they will be.

Becuase both are exports/ mappings that worked before upgrade to 5.10- has anyone seen other export related errors when using civi 5.10?

Am going to wait and see if an upgrade to 5.13 security release will fix this next week. If not, any clues in the meantime would be highly appreciated.